# Ionic ion-datetime - Can't bind to 'first-day-of-week'

Tags: ionic-framework

With the code below, I get a "Can't bind to 'first-day-of-week' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-datetime'."

But it is a known property in the documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#setting-the-first-day-of-the-week

Also if I'm not using a binding and setting it in the template, it is working:
first-day-of-week="1"

How come I get this issue? I'm using the latest version of ionic 6.

```
<ion-datetime
   [locale]="locale"
   [first-day-of-week]="firstDayOfWeek"
   #datetimestart
   [value]="startDateValue"
   (ionChange)="startDateChanged(datetimestart.value)">
</ion-datetime>
```

Comment: The documentation shows usage as `first-day-of-week` and NOT `[first-dayof-week]`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the documentation shows the correct binding and the OP's comment shows he has discovered this, therefore the question is invalid.

Comment: @E.Maggini But how do I then bind to it? Need it to be dynamic

Comment: Please post TS code related to HTML

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
 <ion-datetime
   [locale]="locale"
   first-day-of-week="0"   <---- deafult start from Sunday
   #datetimestart
   [value]="startDateValue"
   (ionChange)="startDateChanged(datetimestart.value)">
</ion-datetime>
```

and number "1" to start from Monday

```
first-day-of-week="1"
```

just change number for other days